# Does standardization result in normal distribution?

Tags: gaussian, multivariate-distribution

I have a question about standardization (subtract mean, divide by standard deviation) of data consisting of different features with different ranges.

I read some information that seemed to be contradictory.

> Standardization
>
> - does not alter the fundamental shape of the data
> - but it gives the data the properties of a normal distribution: mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1

So, does it change the normal distribution or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, standardization does not change the *shape* of the distribution. It centers the distribution by subtracting the mean and scales it by dividing by the standard deviation.

Comment: thanks! It's strange that a lot of blog posts and the like state that standardization renders a distribution normal.. Do they have another definition of normal?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. Can you share a couple of those links?